# Microsoft Excel - Formula to calculate age for a series of rows with different start and end dates?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365

I have a spreadsheet of individuals with a year every time contact was made with them. Each individual has a unique alphanumeric identifier. Each individual has a variable number of entries (rows) depending on the number of times contact was made. I want to calculate how long has passed between the first contact and each subsequent contact. So the first row for an individual will always be '0'.

I've been currently dragging down a formula for each individual, but I have thousands to calculate. Is there a formula that will calculate this 'time since first contact' and change the first contact date when the individual changes?

For example, I am looking for a formula to calculate the 'duration from first contact':

```
Alphanumeric ID : Year Contacted : Duration from first contact

MQ-1122 :         2001 :            0

MQ-1122 :         2003 :            2

MQ-1122 :         2004 :            3

MQ-2233 :         2000 :            0

MT-1122 :         1999 :            0

MT-1122 :         2000 :            1

MT-1122 :         2000 :            1

MT-1122 :         2005 :            6
```

Comment: I think you want to calculate difference of Days between two contacts,, if so then please [Edit] your post and provide adequate data like DATE, since you have provide YEAR only!! Or did you want to get number of year only between two contacts ?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I am only interested in the number of years. The VLOOKUP suggestion below worked for my needs.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming years are always in ascending order, you can take advantage of the fact `VLOOKUP` stops at the first found value. Use:

```
=B1-VLOOKUP(A1,A:B,2,FALSE)
```

And populate down

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly and saved me a ton of time.